# Close all IE window and then clear all data and launch with some url using batch file

Tags: batch-file

How to close all existing IE windows and then delete all the IE cache, session, history, cookies using windows batch script and then launch IE with a specific url in the same script in windows 7. I tried using Chrome it works but not for IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple script batch :)
Works on all system versions.

```
    REM close all IE
    taskkill /IM iexplore.exe /f

    REM Deletes ALL History - 
    RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255

    REM Deletes History Only - 
    RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 1

    REM Deletes Cookies Only - 
    RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2

    REM Deletes Temporary Internet Files Only - 
    RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8

    REM Deletes Form Data Only - 
    RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 16

    REM Deletes Password History Only - 
    RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 32

    REM open IE
    "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "www.google.pl"
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Hoshie, above code excellently solved my problem..only one thing i want to add that may be helpful for others, is that- at the end of code we can use - 
start <line to open ie> ...instead of just <line to open ie> 
so that at the end ie should get closed... But above is excellent for all the version of windows.. Hats off..!!